# Implements a Factory Pattern in java with using Generics

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, factory

I need help with Java Generics.
My model is: I have some classes that extends a Dto (Data Transfer Object) and some classes that extends Entity (The model of my object to DB).
I have

```
interface Mapper<D extends Dto, E extends Entity>{
//Convert a Entity to Dto.
D toDto(E entity);
```

And I have some classes that implements this interface (i.e PersonMapper, BookMapper and so far and so on).

```
@Component    
public class PersonMapper implements Mapper<PersonDto, PersonEntity> {
    //implementation
    }

@Component    
public class BookMapper implements Mapper<BookDto, BookEntity> {
    //implementation
    }
```

What I want to do is to use Factory Pattern in order to select at runtime my Mapper, that depends from a String that I pass in input.

```
@Autowired
private PersonMapper personMapper;
@Autowired
private BookMapper bookMapper;    

public <D extends Dto, E extends Entity> Mapper<D, E> selectMapper(String entity){
      if ("Person".equalsIgnoreCase(entity))
         return personMapper;
      if("Book".equalsIgnoreCase(entity))
        return bookMapper;
      ...
    }
```

With this situation I have the following compile error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from PersonMapper to Mapper<D,E>
```

**My solutions:**

**1)**

```
return (Mapper<D, E>) personMapper;
```

but I have a Warning:

```
Type Safety: `Unchecked class from personMapper to Mapper<D,H>`
```

**2)**

Using WildCard and castingb

```
public Mapper<Dto, Entity> selectMapper(String entity){
          Mapper<? extends Dto, ? extends Entity> toReturn = null;
          if ("Person".equalsIgnoreCase(entity))
             toReturn = personMapper;
          else if("Book".equalsIgnoreCase(entity))
            toReturn = bookMapper;
          ...
          return (Mapper<Dto, Entity>) toReturn;
        }
```

But in this case but I have another time a  Warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Mapper<capture#29-of ? extends Dto,capture#30-of ? extends Entity> to Mapper<Dto,Entity>
```

It works but it doesn't seems to be a clean solution

**3)** Using wildcard as return type:

```
public Mapper<? extends Dto, ? extends HistoryEntity> selectMapper(String entity)
```

but you know, using wildcard as return type is not recommended at all and also doesn't help me because I would like to use this mapper and call mapper.toDto ensuring that the return type is an something that extends Dto.

**====================================================================**

I don't explain why If I write a class constructor like that

```
public Service<D extends Dto, E extends Entity>{  
   public Service(Mapper<D,E> mapper){ 
      this.mapper = mapper; 
   } 
}
```

and than I inject (for example) bookMapper it works.

If, instead, the Mapper<D,E> is in return type I cannot do such a kind of operation.

**====================================================================**

The help that I ask to you is:

**how can I write a solution using clean code principles (avoiding compile warnings, sonarlint issue etc.) in order to implement this kind of logic?**

Thank you very much, I appreciate a lot if you dedicate a little bit of your time helping me to solve my problem.

Comment: This's somewhat a classic problem and as @rzwitserloot suggested - it's reinventing a wheel. Using a sting +an if-else chain is not a good practice anyway, so it's better to replace  the argument `String entity` to at least `Class<? extends Entity> entity` and use a map of `class => mapper` to lookup a mapper. But even that wouldn't provide you with sufficient runtime type-safety because `E` and `D` are unrelated types. There can technically exist many `E` to `D` Mappers out there unless you explicitly bind (through generics) `Entity X` to `Dto Y`

Answer (score 2):

Those vars (D and E) about the caller and not about your code. The D and E are decided by the caller, so there is absolutely no way to guarantee that `PersonDTO` fits.

Make that `Mapper<? extends DTO, ? extends Entity>` (and no variables), and given that those are already the lower bounds, just `Mapper<?, ?>` - that'll work, you can write your `return` statements without any casts and without compiler errors or warnings.

Of course, it means the caller has a mostly useless type.

Generics are entirely 'compile time / write time' based. The JVM (`java.exe`) has no idea what generics are, and in fact most of them don't survive the compilation process. **The one and only purpose of generics is to make the compiler flag incorrect code and avoid some casting, that is all**.

The nature of turning that string into a Mapper is entirely runtime.

Ergo, if `Mapper<?, ?>` isn't sufficient, what you want isn't possible. You'd need to write compile/write-time checkable stuff, so the moment you use a String, it's impossible. For example, a method `getPersonMapper()` can of course return a `Mapper<PersonDTO, PersonEntity>`, no problem.

More generally (heh) it sounds like you're badly reinventing various wheels here. Look at tutorials of JDBI, JOOQ, and Hibernate to get some ideas about how java code is commonly written to interact with databases.

Comment: “if `Mapper<?, ?>` isn't sufficient, what you want isn't possible.”  This is correct, and should be the key takeaway from this answer.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer. I know that with wildcard I don't have compile warning but, you know, using wildcard in return type is not recommended at all.

I don't explain why If I write a class constructor like that

`public Service<D extends Dto, E extends Entity>{

public Service(Mapper<D,E> mapper){
this.mapper = mapper;
}
}`

and than I inject (for example) bookMapper it works.
If, instead, the Mapper<D,E> is in return type I cannot do such a operation

Comment: _using wildcard in return type is not recommended at all_ - this is entirely wrong advice. Either the person/book who told it to you is utterly incorrect and should be disregarded as clueless, or more likely something significant was lost in translation between the author of that advice saying it / writing it and you hearing it / reading it.

Comment: I assume those are Oracle's [Guidelines for Wildcard Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) and [Effective Java](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=%22Do+not+use+wildcard+types+as+return+types.%22&source=bl&ots=y-GgPjn1T4&sig=ACfU3U24OrjI-mj3EB5IXLjkEgNBx7McEA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLiJiRnaX1AhWSzKQKHZnvDccQ6AF6BAgmEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Do%20not%20use%20wildcard%20types%20as%20return%20types.%22&f=false)

Comment: The fact that it's hosted on oracle.com doesn't make it good advice. In this case, they're attempting to highlight the issue that you force callers to deal with it (I _specifically_ highlighted it in my answer!) – but that isn't always a problem, it depends on the API. I can show you many, many `java.*` APIs that return wildcards, so, by their hand it is obvious this is oversimplified advice that doesn't always apply.

Answer (score 0):

Factory Pattern is pattern that assemble or create something by factory methods, in you case what you need is just to get corresponding mapper by name, so there is a simple way to do that since the mapper beans are autowired, adding `String getName()` to Mapper interface then implements it for earch implementation, e.g. in BookMapper

```
    @Override
    public String getName() { return "Book"; }
```

use mapper name as key and mapper bean as value to store mapper beans in a map, then you can retrieve it by its name:

```
@Service
public class SimpleService {
    private BookMapper bookMapper;
    private PersonMapper personMapper;
    private Map<String, Mapper<? extends DTO, ? extends Entity>> mappers = new HashMap<>();

    public SimpleService(BookMapper bookMapper, PersonMapper personMapper) {
        this.bookMapper = bookMapper;
        this.personMapper = personMapper;
        mappers.put(bookMapper.getName(), bookMapper);
        mappers.put(personMapper.getName(), personMapper);
    }

    public Mapper<? extends DTO, ? extends Entity> getMapperByName(String mapperName) {
        return mappers.get(mapperName);
    }
}
```

and you can cast it to corresponding mapper without warning.

```
        PersonMapper p = (PersonMapper) simpleService.getMapperByName("Person");
```

or you can put different mapper in their service and use the service to handle you biz likes codes below, after all, you need specified mappers to do specified operations:

```
     if(personThings){
         personService.doSomeThing();
      }
     if(bookThings){
         bookService.doSomething();
     }
```

Comment: The solution is prone to errors. **1. No 100% guaranteed connection between a name and a mapper**. There maybe several version of `PersonMappers` implementing slightly different mapping logic to different DTOs, or from different entities to the same DTO and human errors in distinct naming are probable. **2. It is not null-safe** unless it returns an Optional or throws an exception. **3. The cast isn't actually safe** and may easily lead to class-cass exceptions at runtime. Additionally it'd raise a critical sonar warning about usage of wildcards on return types

Comment: @dshelya Thanks for comment,  I have considerd about it and mentioned at the last that  can use a service to encapsulate the Entity ,Dto relationship and business logic, then operates the service instead of mapper and no need to worry about  type cast problem

Comment: Thanks for your commens. I will take into account your tips. I appreciate a lot